# Using until either

Tags: grammar

Is this grammatically correct/ is there a better way to say?

> I have been working at .... until either I find a job in my filed of study or  I get accepted to study a Masters degree

Answer (score 1):

**It does not sound quite correct to this US English speaker.**  The problem is not that you can't use *until* and *either* together, but that "have been" and "until" are slightly awkward together here.

"I have been working" is in the [present perfect continuous](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfectcontinuous.html), and indicates an action that began in the indefinite past and extends to the present, but using "until I find" suggests you will continue to do X in the future until Y is true.  This is mixing up tenses in an awkward way.

To use an example that might make it clearer,

> I have been baking the cookies until they are brown

is OK, and says that in the past, you *were* baking the cookies until a point which was also in the past.

> I will be baking the cookies until they are brown

is also OK, because it says that in the future, you *will* bake the cookies until a point which is also in the future.

But

> I have been baking the cookies (in the past, leading up to now) until they are golden brown (in the future)

doesn't quite make sense.

**My recommendation:** Just say "I am working at...until...", because it is your current condition, and using the perfect just complicates the sentence.

Comment: Standon, friend, there is something really wrong with "I have been baking the cookies until they are brown" - I would say that "until" trims the Present Perfect Continuous, which makes it lose the aspect of the present.

Comment: "I have been reading until morning" is probably wrong since it is definitely said from the Present and it is not identifiable to either be true or false at the moment of speaking, you may well not be reading it now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a native speaker but from personal experience the "until" most often comes after "either" in such sentences and is mostly used with plans, agreements, suppositions, or decisions, for example:

- I am planning to work here either until I find a better job or (until I) finish studying.
- I suppose I'll work here either until I find a better job or until my father recovers.
- I will work here either until I find a better job or until this factory shuts down.
- I am working here either until next summer or until I get my visa.
- I am going to work here either until I get tired or my boss throws me out.

Answer (score -1):

It seems fine with a few changes I would make.

> I have been working at *job* until either I find a job in my *field* of study or I get accepted to *begin studies for a Master's degree*.

Comment: Definitely doesn't sound right to my ear. The Present Perfect with future plans just don't go together. "I have been eating until I see the moon tonight" is plain wrong.